# How to remove black overlay and ellipse in Universal App AppBar

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I'm developing a small Universal App under Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 and one of the first things I need to do is add an AppBar in my XAML code to display the standard bar with button at the top of the screen. But for some reason, when I write the following code, I get an ellipse (3 points) at the right and when I click it, immediately to the left of it, there's a black box that I want to get rid of. All I want is to add buttons to it.

Here is my code:
[image]

Here is what the output shows:

[image]

There's nothing in the code that displays this black area that overlays my buttons when I click the ellipse. Where is this coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791888/hiding-the-ellipsis-within-an-appbar/31798573#31798573). You should use `CommandBar` instead of `AppBar` in UWP. It also tells you how to customize the `CommandBar` to get rid of the ellipses. One suggestion, you should paste your code as in **text** rather than picture.

Comment: But this forces me to take the entire Template and add it to my page or my application. A big price to pay just to remove the ellipse. Is there no other way? The Template is hundreds of lines of XAML code.

Comment: There is no other way. Restyling n retemplating is the beauty of xaml UI system, I have thousands lines of fully customised styles n templates sitting inside different resource dictionaries in my project. You want custom UI? This is what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Justin XL's excellent response, to hide the ellipse in my BottomAppBar, I had to go to App.xaml. Near the bottom of the newly created AppBar style, set the ExpandButton visibility to collapsed:

```
<Button x:Name="ExpandButton" ... Visibility="Collapsed" .../>
```